# How to refer to a base instance python gtk widget from a function in a module

Tags: python, inheritance, gtk

I am writing a Python GTK application for studying some sort of math data. The main script has a single class with only three methods: `__INIT__`, main(self) for starting the loop and delete_event for killing it.

`__INIT__` creates the GUI, which includes a TextBuffer and TextView widgets so that the analysis functions (defined on a separate functions.py module) can output their results to a common log/message area. A relevant extract follows:

```
include module functions(.py)

(...)

class TURING:

  def __init__(self):

    self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)

    (...)

    self.logscroll = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    self.logscroll.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)

    self.logbuffer = gtk.TextBuffer()

    self.logpage = gtk.TextView(self.logbuffer)
    self.logpage.set_editable(gtk.FALSE)
    self.logpage.set_cursor_visible(gtk.FALSE)
    self.logpage.set_wrap_mode(gtk.WRAP_CHAR)
    self.logscroll.add(self.logpage)
    self.logscroll.show()
    self.logpage.show()

    (...)

    enditer = self.logbuffer.get_end_iter()
    self.logbuffer.insert(enditer, 'Welcome!')

    (...)

  def main(self):
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  turing = TURING()
  turing.main()
```

The intermediate two lines successfully print a welcome message onto the message area defined by self.logpage.

Now, one of the functions in method **functions** checks whether the database is up to date and if not asks the user to load a new batch of raw data.

One way of doing this is to include a menu item that triggers that function, like this:

item_dataCheck.connect("activate", functions.data_check, '')

`functions.data_check` runs fine however when it tries to write its output to self.logbuffer an error is thrown complaining that menu item `item_dataCheck` has no property `logbuffer`. The offending code is

```
 enditer = self.logbuffer.get_end_iter()
 self.logbuffer.insert(enditer, 'Please update the database.')
```

Obviously the name self is representing the widget that invoked the function, viz., `item_dataCheck`. My question is how can I from `functions.data_check` refer directly to `logbuffer` as a member of the `turing` instance of the `TURING` class. I tried to write

```
 enditer = turing.logbuffer.get_end_iter()
 turing.logbuffer.insert(enditer, 'Please update the database.')
```

but that's is not working. I have tried hard to find a solution but with no success.

I believe the matter is quite trivial and I know I still have some serious conceptual problems with Python and OOP, but any help will be heartly appreciated. (I started out card punching Fortran programs on a Burroughs mainframe, so I could count on some community mercy...)

Answer (score 1):

You can provide additional arguments when connecting signals to functions or methods.  So your handler `functions.data_check` can accept extra arguments apart from `self`:

```
def data_check(self, logbuffer):
    # ...
```

Then, you can [connect with arguments](http://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/class-gobject.html#method-gobject--connect):

```
item_dataCheck.connect("activate", functions.data_check, logbuffer)
```

Also, the `self` parameter is normally used as the first parameter in method definitions.  This is a very strong convention so you should use `obj` or something similar instead.  Specially since your signal handlers may be methods too; in which case you could mess it up with its arguments.

Comment: Hi and thanks.I see what you mean but still do not understand how to make data_check realize that logbuffer belongs to the instance turing of the TURING class.

Comment: @user1106979: Python is a dynamic language, there type of a variable is only known at run time, so you normally don't worry what type an object has as long as it provides the interface you need.  However, if you need to check the type of an object, you can use [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/functions.html#isinstance)